# Python Complex Number Formatting of zero imaginary part

Tags: python, string, formatting, complex-numbers

Is it possible to format a complex number in such a way that the real part is not displayed if it is zero?

I am currently using `'{:.3g}'.format(x)` which does a great job of suppressing unnecessary zeros, but I still get numbers of the form `0+0.5j`, which should be cast into `0.5j`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`str` and `repr` seem to work:

```
>>> str(0.5j)
'0.5j'

>>> repr(0.5j)
'0.5j'
```

Comment: They work like a charm, but could you give me a hint how to only show three digits after the decimal point, for instance?

Comment: @Faser Hmm, I don't know much about formatting complex numbers, I only came up with hacks like stripping the '0+' away with `'{:.3g}'.format(x).lstrip('0+' * (x.real == 0))` or rounding the number like `str(complex(round(x.real, 3), round(x.imag, 3)))`.